# Set fragments parameters programatically in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, compatibility

How to set parameters like height, width ,margins for fragments programatically. I am adding fragments like

```
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    MyListFragment myListFragment = new MyListFragment();
    fragmentTransaction.add(1, myListFragment);

    DetailFragment detailFragment = new DetailFragment();
    fragmentTransaction.add(1, detailFragment);

    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Also I am using compatabilty jar like android-support-v4.jar.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think that there are methods related to the stuff you want to add programatically in the fragments.Or try using `getActivity().methods u want` to get some methods.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How to set parameters like height, width ,margins for fragments programatically

Fragments do not have "parameters like height, width ,margins". `View` and `ViewGroup` have "parameters like height, width ,margins". So, you either adjust the container into which you are placing the fragment (which, for some strange reason, you have declared as `1` in your examples above), or you adjust the `View` that your `Fragment` returns from `onCreateView()`.

Comment: But we can set parameters for fragment, if we declare it in xml file like                                                           <fragment
        android:name="com.android.bvbi.MyListFragment"
        android:id="@+id/listFragment"
        android:layout_width="150dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
         ></fragment>

Comment: "which, for some strange reason, you have declared as 1 in your examples above" .  Here 1 is the id of linearlayout (created programatically) to which I am adding the fragments.  What is the better approach for setting ids programatically for views and viewgroups?

Comment: @PrabhuM: "But we can set parameters for fragment" -- that is shorthand for setting parameters on the view returned by `onCreateView()`. `Fragment` is not a `View` and so does not have height, width, etc. "What is the better approach for setting ids programatically for views and viewgroups?" -- safest is to use ID resources: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Id Low numbers like `1` should work, though, AFAIK.

Comment: I'm really sorry but this answer made me laugh so hard. The answer is correct! But the part where @CommonsWare said "Which, for some strange reason, you have declared as 1..." has made my day :) The OP obviously must've seen that the parameter as an int and passed in to it any ol' int. Number 1 in this case of course.

Answer (score 0):

CommonsWare's additional info that you can adjust the View returned by onCreateView(), got me thinking about another approach: simply get the Fragments view and then adjust the LayoutParams of that.

```
// use the appropriate LayoutParams type and appropriate size/behavior
FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
theFragment().getView().setLayoutParams(params);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a valid case here to add margins programatically on the fragment's view and not on the container it's inflated into.

If you want to have your container layout shared with other views for instance.

In my case I have a full-screen `FrameLayout` containing a button at the top, and the entire screen is then taken by the inflated fragment.
I could nest two `FrameLayout`s one inside the other, but that's not good for draw performance, the better option would be to inflate the fragment directly into the root `FrameLayout`, but give its `view` `topMargin` to prevent it from hiding the button.

Here's some code:

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
Fragment fragment = new MyFragment();
fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, fragment, "main").commit();

// wait for the fragment to inflate its view within container
container.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new OnLayoutChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
        if (fragment.getView() != null) {
            LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, MATCH_PARENT);
            lp.topMargin = 50; // you need to translate DP to PX here!
            fragment.getView().setLayoutParams(lp);

            container.removeOnLayoutChangeListener(this); // prevent infinite loops
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: @CommonsWare would you agree? is this bad practice?