# Set the Fragment Layout Margin Programmatically at run time

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I want to set the Layout margin of fragment programmatically. Is there way to do this.

As I tried with MapView like this.

```
LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) mapView.getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
mapView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Can it be achieved same in case of fragment.

Comment: for reference. This question explains it: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10683374/3184778

Answer (score -1):

In the onCreateView method of the fragment you could use the following code to set the view programmatically:

```
// Inflate the layout for this fragment
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sample_fragment, container, false);
    LayoutParams layoutParams=new LayoutParams(width, height);
    layoutParams.setMargins(leftMargin, topMargin, 0, 0);
    view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```